# Java http-server. 404

Tags: java, сервер, http, веб-сервер

После загугливания `http-server java` информации нашлось не особа много. Конкретно нашел статейку со следующем примером:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8189), 0);
            server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null); // default executor
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is a test response";

            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());

            OutputStream out = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            out.write(response.getBytes());
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Запустил сервер. И в браузере вбил: http://127.0.0.1:8189/.

Ответом был:

> 404 Not Found.

Что пошло не так?

Comment: В метод handle я поставил sout(1) для проверки и выяснил, что этот метод не вызывается.

Comment: Вы же контекст как `/test` определили. Попробуйте `http://127.0.0.1:8189/test`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal value for path or protocol
А если просто /127.0.0.1:8189/test то тоже самое, 404

Comment: server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
И заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
```